# Automated way to provide git password into interactive shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, subprocess, tty

> **What specific syntax needs to be changed in order to get the code below to interactively provide a password when it receives a response asking for password?**

**THE REQUIREMENT:**

A Python 3 program must automate the process of cloning private remote github repositories into a local compute instance.

Password must NOT be leaked into logs.  Therefore, we cannot use:  `git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository-name.git`

Must run on both Linux and Windows.

**CURRENT CODE:**

The Python3 code that we are currently experimenting with for this purpose is:

```
def runShellCommandInWorkingDir(commandToRun, workingDir):  
  proc = subprocess.Popen( commandToRun,cwd=workingDir, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)  
  while True:  
    line = proc.stdout.readline()  
    if line:  
      thetext=line.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\r|\n')  
      decodedline=ansi_escape.sub('', thetext)  
      print(decodedline)  
    else:  
      break  

repoUrlCred = "https://" + username + "@github.com/" + username + "/repository-name.git"  
gitCloneCommand = "git clone " + repoUrlCred  
runShellCommandInWorkingDir(gitCloneCommand, "D:\\path\\to\\working\\Directory\\")
```

**CURRENT RESULTS:**

When we run the current code as shown above, the Python 3 program halts the program midway through and asks the user to manually enter the password as follows:

```
Cloning into 'repository-name'...  
Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.  
Password for 'https://username@github.com':
```

> **What specific Python 3 syntax must be changed above in order to get the Python 3 program to automatically enter the password during runtime without stopping to ask the user for it?**

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion :

- generate an ssh key dedicated to this client
- register the public key in GitHub for user `username`
- clone the repository using ssh